# Is the package nixos-rebuild for a distribution different from nixos?

Tags: nix, nixos

I've read the [documentation for nix-rebuild](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nixos-rebuild). It look like it is only intended to use in nixos. The constant $NIX_PATH (/etc/nixos/configuration.nix) can be found only on a nixos distribution..
But in the [package manager](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=22.11&show=nixos-rebuild&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=Nixos-rebuild) , there is a possibility to install the package a distribution different from nixos.

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.nixos-rebuild
```

Can this be useful for a non nix-os distribution?

Comment: I imagine this would be useful for building a NixOS configuration for a virtual machine without having to use NixOS as the host OS.

Comment: This is a very open ended question. Useful for what purpose?

Answer (score 0):

To deploy NixOS on top of a different distribution the tools are different to nixos-rebuild.

If you are thinking of replacing your hosts OS with NixOS (instead of just Nix as say a package manager https://nixos.org/download.html#download-nix) then my suggestion is to look at one of three options:

1. https://github.com/cleverca22/nix-tests/tree/master/kexec
2. https://nixos.wiki/wiki/NixOS_Installation_Guide#Making_the_installation_media
3. https://github.com/elitak/nixos-infect

Best regards Nigel